# PHP - What's a good way to handle this?

Tags: php, logic

OK, let's say when a user selects a country, they are also added with a "federation". These federations are pretty much region-centric.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
function getFedration($country_iso) {
 // 6 federations
 // afc = asian nations
 // caf = african nations
 // cocacaf = north & central america and Caribbean nations
 // conmebol = south america
 // ofc = Oceanian nations
 // uefa = european nations

$afc = array("Japan", "China", "South Korea");
$caf = array("Cameroon", "Chad", "Ivory Coast");
$concacaf = array("United States" , "Canada", "Mexico");
$conmebol = array("Argetina", "Brazil", "Chile");
$ofc = array("Fiji", "New Zealand", "Samoa");
$uefa = array("Spain", "England", "Montenegro");

/*
PSEUDO-code

If $country_iso is in either of six arrays... mark that as the federation...

*/

return $federation;

}
```

I know, it says a country's name but when it comes down to it, it will be country's iso like `JP` instead of `Japan`, `CN` instead of `China`, et cetera.

So, I was wondering, is this a feasible thing or is there a better way you'd think?

Comment: what is the output you want? can you please clarify?

Comment: Is this a good way to handle what I'm doing or is there an easier way? I want, when a user selects a country to look for country in one of the six arrays and return...

Comment: @weka: to confirm by giving an example, if `$country_iso` is say "England" (but preferably "EN"), do you want "federation" to be "uefa"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right, bob-the-destroyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting all federations into an array, in order to loop through it? Makes things easier, like so:

```
function countryToFederation($country_iso) {
    $federations = array(
        "afc" => array("Japan", "China", "South Korea"),
        "caf" => array("Cameroon", "Chad", "Ivory Coast"),
        "concacaf" => array("United States" , "Canada", "Mexico"),
        "conmebol" => array("Argetina", "Brazil", "Chile"),
        "ofc" => array("Fiji", "New Zealand", "Samoa"),
        "uefa" => array("Spain", "England", "Montenegro"),
    );


    foreach($federations as $federation) {
        if(in_array($country_iso, $federation)) {
            return $federation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'` starting on the first line where it says `"afc"`

Answer (score 1):

If a federation can only belong to one country, I would create one array instead:

```
$countryToFederationMap = array(
    'Japan' => 'AFC',
    'China' => 'AFC',
    'Cameroon' => 'CAF',
    // ...
);
```

Then the federation is simply:

```
return $countryToFederationMap[$country];
```